# Detect service availability from Activity's onCreate

Tags: android, android-service

From within the `onCreate` within an `Activity`, I'd like to be able to detect whether a `Service` in a different application (that I'm also writing) is available and running. The problem with AIDL is that there is no synchronous option. I'd like my activity to actually wait to see if the `Service` is available and act accordingly if it is not.

The best answer I've come up with is for the service to open a TCP socket and for the Activity to try to connect to it. If that succeeds, then the Activity's `onCreate` will know that the service is available. However this is a kludge at best.

So, bottom line: how can my Activity's `onCreate` synchronously check to see if an external `Service` is available and take action before returning from the `onCreate` routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the List returned by public `List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> getRunningServices (int maxNum)`. Each `ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo` contains the information you need

Check the API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html)

```
ActivityMAnager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rsiList = am.getRunningServices (999);
boolean found = null;
for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi: rsiList) {
    if (rsi.service.getPackageName().equals("MYPACKAGE") {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    // do whatever
} else {
    // alternative
}
```